# actionscript graphics connecting 2 sprites

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

Using Flex 4 Builder

Is it possible to draw 2 rectangular shapes of "Box A" and "Box B" and place them apart, next, adding a magnetic line (black line) between them which will keep them connected without having to manually update the line xy position?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by manually, practically your black line should be drawn between two points defined by BoxA & BoxB coordinates, anytime you move either of the boxes, you should call a method that will refresh your line.

As long as your points are referenced to BoxA & BoxB positions, refreshing the line is only a matter of recalling the method you've used to draw it.

```
      //Pseudo Code
      define BoxA position
      define BoxB position
      define PointA PointA = new Point( BoxA.centerX , BoxA.centerY)
      define PointB PointB = new Point( BoxB.centerX , BoxB.centerY)

      define drawLine method // draw line between PointA & PointB
      drawLine();

      move( BoxB ); //will change the value of PointB
      drawLine();
```

Comment: I think I got the easier and smarter idea. However, I have no idea about collision detection as to which is easier and better.

Comment: If you have a better idea, please share!

Comment: The idea is to use 2 pass methods or eventlistener with bindable x y positions, I think we already got the idea in real life.